# cygwin support for C++11 in g++4.9.2

Tags: c++, c++11, cygwin

I am trying to test some C++11 code on Windows 7 under cygwin, and am getting compiling errors for functions that are defined starting with C++11, such as `std::log2` and `std::round`. I am compiling with `g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp`, using gcc 4.9.2. Here is some minimal example that fails to compile:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
        auto x = std::log2(10);
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

error:

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:5:11: error: ‘log2’ is not a member of ‘std’
  auto x = std::log2(10);
           ^
test.cpp:5:11: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/cmath:44:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/math.h:305:15: note:   ‘log2’
 extern double log2 _PARAMS((double));
```

Is this a known bug in cygwin's g++ porting? The code above works fine on any Linux/UNIX flavour supporting C++11.

Comment: Looks related to [this](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2015-03/msg00247.html)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour oh thanks! I was actually the person who filled the bug, didn't know they fixed it :)

Comment: It looked like you had filed the bug report, so I was a little confused. Otherwise I would have just provided an answer since it was indeed fixed. Alternatively you could provide a self-answer explaining you filed a bug report and it was fixed. Others will probably have this issue as well.

Comment: provided the answer. was actually quite surprised no one reported it before, I guess very few people use numerical simulations under cygwin.

Comment: It seems to apply to GCC 4.9.2 from MSYS2 too. On GCC 4.8.1 from vanilla MinGW/MSYS `std::round` and the like work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seems to be a [bug](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2015-03/msg00247.html) related to cygwin implementation, thanks to Shafik Yaghmour for pointing it out.

The issue is now fixed via a patch for `<cmath>`, also at the link provided above.

Comment: is this bug fixed in g++4.9.3 ? Thanks

Comment: @sujithvm not sure, better to check the cygwin bug report system

Comment: @sujithvm std::round is not defined in 4.9.3 in my testing. It is defined in 5.1.0. Not sure when exactly it got fixed.