# Cygwin gcc.4.9.2 : error: '::lrintl' has not been declared

Tags: c++11, cygwin, cmath, gcc4.9, newlib

This question is related to this thread: [cygwin support for C++11 in g++4.9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997206/cygwin-support-for-c11-in-g4-9-2)

I had the same issue:

```
error: ‘log2’ is not a member of ‘std’
```

I applied the proposed patch, only to get another error.
Including cmath here

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
        std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
}
```

returns this error

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
In file included from test.cpp:1:0:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/cmath:1107:11: error: '::lrintl' has not been declared
   using ::lrintl;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/cmath:1129:11: error: '::rintl' has not been declared
   using ::rintl;
```

I asked for help on the cygwin IRC channel:

```
[23:02] <XXX> hi, has anyone had problems with gcc 4.9.2 in cygwin? i encountered the problem discussed here : https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2015-03/msg00247.html
[23:03] <XXX> yet, if i apply the patch, i get another error: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/cmath:1107:11: error: '::lrintl' has not been declared
[23:28] <YYY> long double functions are still missing on cygwin
[23:30] <XXX> so is there no way to make it work then?
[23:31] <YYY> sure, help add the missing functions to newlib/cygwin
[23:34] <XXX> i am not using any long double functions in my code -- so i assume including cmath does not work for anybody?
[23:35] <YYY> just drop the std:: instead
[23:37] <XXX> sorry, i'm not sure what you mean. remove 'std::' where ?
```

Sadly, the conversation ended there. I have no clue where I should 'drop std::' nor if that resolves the problem.
Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Unpatched `<cmath>` works fine here if I do:

```cpp
auto x = log2(10);
```

instead of:

```cpp
auto x = std::log2(10);
```

Perhaps that is what YYY means by 'drop std::'.

If you must use the patched `<cmath>`, you can either comment out the two offending lines or if you'd prefer not to modify the header any more than you already have, add some dummy definitions of `rintl` and `lrintl` before you include it. For example:

```cpp
#include <stdexcept>
long double rintl(long double arg) { throw std::runtime_error("rintl not implemented"); }
long lrintl(long double arg) { throw std::runtime_error("lrintl not implemented"); }

#include <cmath>
```