# C++/ name conflict: how to exclude a previously defined function

Tags: c++, c++11, name-conflict

I want to write log2() function for a new datatype that I defined myself Array. So it will look like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

Array log2(Array& A)
{
    Array C=A;

    for (int i=0; i<A.size(); i++)
         C[i]=log2(A[i]);

    return C;
}
```

despite other functions like sin, cos, etc, this one (log2) is not declared under std namespace. so even using the following

```
std::log2(A[i])
```

the compiler does not resolve that inside log2 is suppoed to be the built-in c function. I persist to use the same name (log2) for simplicity of the code.

This is the error message

error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'Array&' from expression of type 'double'

SOLVED: It worked when I switched to -std::C++ 11.

Comment: I don't understand, how question title and the actual question fit together. The question sounds, like you get a compiler/linker error. Please post that error message.

Comment: here's the error:>  error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'TArray&' from expression of type 'double'

Comment: It is if you include `<cmath>` then it should be in the standard namespace.

Comment: it works for other built-ins, except log2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`std::log2`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log2) was introduced in C++11. Make sure you have a C++11 compliant compiler (e.g. gcc4.8 or later, compile with `-std=c++11`), and use `std::log2` inside your function.

If you don't use `std::log2`, then the compiler cannot find the standard function (as you are not `using namespace std;`) and tries to use yours, which of course is not defined for `double`s, and you get an error.

My personal opinion is that you should try to avoid naming your function the same as a standard one, due to headaches that can later appear.

Comment: Open a terminal and type `g++ --version` to see the version. Also make sure you use `-std=c++11` when you compile your code. However there may be a bug (I reported it actually long time ago), see https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2015-03/msg00247.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997206/cygwin-support-for-c11-in-g4-9-2 Not sure if mingw is affected.

Comment: @AliQajar Glad it helped!

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know, the built-in function `log2` is not declared in `namespace std`.
You should use the following code to call the standard `log2` function:

```
log2(A[i]);
```

I hope my answer helped.

Comment: in C++11, it is declared under std:: like other built-in math functions in <cmath>. I added C++11 switch and it worked. It can be called as std::log2()

Comment: That's exactly what the code in the question does, and it didn't work.